Regex: Remove more than 2 consecutive <br>?
In a string, I would like to replace any occurrences of:
<br /><br /><br /> (or more) 

with:
<br /><br />

This has worked for replacing 2 or more consecutive occurrences of the letter e with an asterisk:
Dim strInput As String = "Thee brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
Label1.Text = Regex.Replace(strInput, "e{2,}", "*")

Giving:
Th* brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

These regex haven't worked for replacing two or more consecutive occurrences of the HTML breaks with an asterisk:
Dim strInput As String = "Thee <br /><br /><br /> brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
Label1.Text = Regex.Replace(strInput, "\b<br />{2,}\b", "*")
Label1.Text = Regex.Replace(strInput, "\b<br />\b{2,}", "*")
Label1.Text = Regex.Replace(strInput, "\b<br />\b {2,}", "*")

Can anyone please give a syntax that will work?
(I could temporarily swap out all occurrences of the HTML breaks in the string with say [HTML-Linebreak] before executing the code if that would be easier. Then I could replace them back after.)

In the .../>{2,}\b and the ...\b {2,} the quantifier (the {2,}) applies to the > and the space respectively. You need to enclose the part of the regex that needs repeating in brackets, as shown in the answers by @TranQuocBao and @SamPaulIsaac.

It's very much not obvious to me how the current dupe target addresses the question.  I'd @-tag Wiktor to ask but it seems like SO only automatically finds someone if they've already commented.

Try it, it worked with me: Regex.Replace(strInput, "(<br\s*/?>\s*){3,}", "<br /><br />")
    Dim strInput As String = "Thee <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(strInput, "(<br\s*/?>\s*){3,}", "<br /><br />"))


That worked. Thanks very much.
